# Activating a closed workbook with dates using partial string seach

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file named "PLDriverSensitivityReportSIN__21112019_172032.xls"

- "PLDriverSensitivityReportSIN__" is constant
- "21112019" is the date that changes everyday
- "172032" is random

I would like to have an Input box prompting " Key in today's date (ddmmyyyy)" and save this to a variable "Today"

**Objective:** The macro would prompt the user for today's date using the Input box and does a partial search in a specified directory for today's file. It should ignore the random element at end of the string.

The script should load the file based on the input `"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\PLDriverSensitivityReportSIN__" & Today & "_*" & ".xls"`

The current code I have is not dynamic - please see below

```
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\PLDriverSensitivityReportSIN__21112019_172032.xls")
```

Comment: You can use the `Dir()`function with partial string will find your file. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function)

Comment: Never use InputBox for getting a date value unless there is absolutely no other way. And if you must, make sure you validate it as a date before using it in your code. If you are asking them to enter today's date, there is no reason for that, as you can just use the `Date()` or `Now()` functions to return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should help you achieve your desired result, it uses the Dir() function to find the Workbook using a wildcard then if the workbook is found, it will open it:

```
Sub OpenWildcard()
Dim sName As String
'Declare the variable for the workbook.
Today = InputBox("Enter Today's Date", "Enter Date")
'Prompt for date entry
'Today = Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")
'Or use today's date without prompting the user for input
sName = Dir("C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\PLDriverSensitivityReportSIN__" & Today & "_*" & ".xls")
'check if file is found
If sName <> "" Then
'if found then open
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\" & sName
End If
End Sub
```